# Read entire group in an HDF5 file using a pandas.HDFStore

Tags: python, pandas, hdfstore

I have an HDF file like that:

```py
>>> dataset.store
... <class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
... File path: ../data/data_experiments_01-02-03.h5
... /exp01/user01    frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->221,ncols->124,indexers->[index])
... /exp01/user02    frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->163,ncols->124,indexers->[index])
... /exp01/user03    frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->145,ncols->124,indexers->[index])
... /exp02/user01    frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->194,ncols->124,indexers->[index])
... /exp02/user02    frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->145,ncols->124,indexers->[index])
... /exp03/user03    frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->348,ncols->124,indexers->[index])
... /exp03/user01    frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->240,ncols->124,indexers->[index])
```

from which I want to retrieve all the users (userXY) from one of the experiments (exp0Z) and append them into a single big DataFrame. I have tried `store.get('exp03')` obtaining the following error:

```py
>>> store.get('exp03')
... 
... ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
... TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
... <ipython-input-109-0a2e29e9e0a4> in <module>()
... ----> 1 dataset.store.get('/exp03')
... 
... /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.pyc in get(self, key)
...     613         if group is None:
...     614             raise KeyError('No object named %s in the file' % key)
... --> 615         return self._read_group(group)
...     616 
...     617     def select(self, key, where=None, start=None, stop=None, columns=None,
... 
... /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.pyc in _read_group(self, group, **kwargs)
...    1277 
...    1278     def _read_group(self, group, **kwargs):
... -> 1279         s = self._create_storer(group)
...    1280         s.infer_axes()
...    1281         return s.read(**kwargs)
... 
... /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.pyc in _create_storer(self, group, format, value, append, **kwargs)
...    1160                 else:
...    1161                     raise TypeError(
... -> 1162                         "cannot create a storer if the object is not existing "
...    1163                         "nor a value are passed")
...    1164             else:
... 
... TypeError: cannot create a storer if the object is not existing nor a value are passed
```

I can retrieve a single user by calling `store.get('exp03/user01')`, so I guess it is possible to iterate the `store.keys()` and append manually the retrieved dataframes, but I wonder if it is possible to do so in a single call to `store.get()` or other similar method.

EDIT: Note that dataset is a class that contains my pandas.HDFstore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not implemented, though could be a nice feature. (and FYI I would not have it set by default in `.get(...)` because its not explicit enough (e.g. should it ALWAYS read ALL the tables, too much guessing), but could have an argument to control which sub-tables I suppose. If you are interested in implemented this, pls put to github.

You can use some internal functions to make this pretty easy though (and you could even pass a `where` to each of the selects.

```
In [13]: store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5',mode='w')

In [14]: store.append('df/foo1',DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2)))

In [15]: store.append('df/foo2',DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2)))

In [16]: pd.concat([ store.select(node._v_pathname) for node in store.get_node('df') ])
Out[16]: 
          0         1
0 -0.495847 -1.449251
1 -0.494721  1.572560
2  1.219985  0.280878
3 -0.419651  1.975562
4 -0.489689 -2.712342
5 -0.022466 -0.238129
6 -1.195269 -0.028390
7 -0.192648  1.220730
8  1.331892  0.950508
9 -0.790354 -0.743006
0 -0.761820  0.847983
1 -0.126829  1.304889
2  0.667949 -1.481652
3  0.030162 -0.111911
4 -0.433762 -0.596412
5 -1.110968  0.411241
6 -0.428930  0.086527
7 -0.866701 -1.286884
8 -0.649420  0.227999
9 -0.100669 -0.205232

[20 rows x 2 columns]

In [17]: store.close()
```

Keep in mind though if I were doing this, their is little reason to have SEPARATE nodes when the data is the same; its MUCH more efficient to have it in a single table with say a field that indicates its name or id or whatever.

Almost always I use different nodes for heteregenous data (not necessary different dtypes, but different 'types' of data).

That said, you can organize however you like!

Comment: Thanks @Jeff, I've already added an [**issue**](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6833) to github proposing this new feature.